# NpgsqlDataAdapter Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, npgsql

I'n using .Net provider for Postgresql and when i run the following code  I got "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error.

### I run the following code from a form:

```
DataTable x = new DataTable(); 
x = cmdGetRow("select * from employee;"); // I get the error here
```

### Which calls this function:

```
public DataTable cmdGetRow(String SQL)
        {
                NpgsqlDataAdapter NpAdapter = new NpgsqlDataAdapter();
                DataSet dset = new DataSet("hr");
                NpAdapter.SelectCommand = new NpgsqlCommand(SQL, dbConnection);
                NpAdapter.Fill(dset, "employee");
                return dset.Tables["employee"];

        }
```

Can you help me please.

Comment: Which line inside cmdGetRow() gives you error?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
DataTable x = new DataTable(); 
cmdGetRow("select * from employee;", ref x);

public void cmdGetRow(String SQL, ref table)
{
    NpgsqlDataAdapter NpAdapter = new NpgsqlDataAdapter();
    DataSet dset = new DataSet("hr");
    NpAdapter.SelectCommand = new NpgsqlCommand(SQL, dbConnection);
    NpAdapter.Fill(dset, "employee");
    table = dset.Tables["employee"];
}
```

Comment: Change: NpgsqlDataAdapter NpAdapter = new NpgsqlDataAdapter();
To: NpgsqlDataAdapter npAdapter = new NpgsqlDataAdapter();
I guess your object name ("NpAdapter") represents the type as it is now.
If that doesn't help, try to find out, which object isn't instanciated properly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you: before getting data from database make sure there is a connection and the connection is open.

```
public DataTable cmdGetRow(String SQL)
    {
            string conString = String.Format("Server={0};Port={1};User Id={2};Password={3};Database={4};",
            _server, _port, _userId, _password, _database);
            NpgsqlConnection connection = new NpgsqlConnection(conString);
            connectin.Open();
            NpgsqlDataAdapter command = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
            DataSet dataSet = new Dataset();
            dataSet.Reset();
            command.Fill(dataSet);
            return dataSet.Tables[0];
    }
```